# Why this function is in $C^\infty((0,\infty);H^1(\Omega))$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\lambda_j$ be the eigenvalues of the Neumann Laplacian on a bounded domain $\Omega$ with eigenvectors $\varphi_j$, which we know are smooth.

Given a function $u \in H^{\frac 12}(\Omega)$ with $\int_\Omega u = 0$, define $$v(x,y) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-y\lambda_k^{\frac 12}}(u,\varphi_k)_{L^2}\varphi_k(x).$$

The claim is $v \in H^1(\Omega \times (0,\infty))$ and $v \in C^\infty((0,\infty);H^1(\Omega))$.

I don't see why $v(y) \in H^1(\Omega)$ for a.a. $y$. I know the basis functions $\varphi_k$ are smooth, but that can't be the full reason. If it were, then by this logic, can we not just say that every $u \in L^2(\Omega)$ is in $H^1(\Omega)$, since $u=\sum (u,\varphi_k)\varphi_k$, and $\nabla u = \sum (u,\varphi_k)\nabla \varphi_k$?

Comment: These damping terms somehow 'kill' the non-regularity. This is the idea behind. I have no idea how to proceed, though.

Comment: @daw I think it is because: one can define $H^{\frac 12}(\Omega) := \{ u \in L^2(\Omega) \mid \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda_k^{\frac 12}|(u,\varphi_k)|^2 < \infty\}$, and give it an alternative norm using this expression in the definition. THen the result should follow. But I do find it strange that the damping term (independent of the space variable $x$) gives spatialregularity !!!